# ASP.net MVC 5 not select between dates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm creating a reservation application. I need to check for free spots in a period of time. Each reservation got a ArrivalDate and a LeaveDate and a spotId is the foreign key in this table.

When I create a reservation, for example from 1-3-2015 to 20-3-2015, the spot *can't* be reservable *but* after this period of time it must be possible to reserve this spot! So, based on what a user is filling in in the calendar it should check for free spot in the period of time the user chose.

How do I do this? I got a query but it does not work:

Code:
RegisterController

```
        public ActionResult ShowAvailableSpots(DateTime ArrivalDate, DateTime LeaveDate)
    {
        var query = _campingspotrepository.SelectAvailableSpots(ArrivalDate, LeaveDate);
        ViewBag.CampingSpotId = new SelectList(query, "CampingSpotId", "SpotName");

        return View();
    }
```

My repository SelectAvailableSpots:

```
        public IQueryable SelectAvailableSpots(DateTime ArrivalDate, DateTime LeaveDate)
    {
        var query2 = db.Spots.Where(c => !db.Reservations.Any(r => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.ArrivalDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ArrivalDate)
        && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.LeaveDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(LeaveDate)));

        return query2;  
    }
```

My view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CampingSpotId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CampingSpotId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

My Table for the Reservation

[image]

My Table for CampingSpot

[image]

Comment: So you need Available Slot what for a Spot? Correct me if I am wrong, there is a Spot G1, which is already reserved 5-Mar to 20-Mar and 1-Apr to 10-Apr. If the user searches 21-Mar to 25-Mar, it should be listed. Right?

Comment: Hi,  yes that is correct. It should be listed when there is no reservation on the spot for that date. If the user select a date from 16mar till 25mar for example it should not be listed.. because it overlaps the other date...

Comment: So, no overlapping allowed.

Comment: Well... maybe than it must suggest a other date(3days later) so they can reserv it. If i want that i must make a spot schedule so the user can see that the spot is reserved, no idea how tho..  one thing is for sure.. the system must notice when there is a overlap

Comment: Can you follow me? Sry for my English

Comment: Yes, then first you need to find out the free slots for the given date range, and apply your condition on the result. Thats the best approach.

Comment: Yes, but to find those free slots i must firstly check free dates and make them selectable via my calendar... and gray the unavailable dates out..

Comment: Thats great! but where do i begin haha, i will check

Comment: You can get it from Reservation table and grey the calendar in which the Spot already reserved.